# Obtener el id en un ImageButton de un gridview en ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, webforms

Tengo un gridview de una serie de objetos. Tengo también  un ImageButton en cada fila que quiero que tenga el Id de cada objeto en el CommandName, para después encontrarlo en la base de datos.

Botón en el gridview:

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="btnVer" CommandName="CONSULTAR" CommandArgument='' ImageUrl="~/ver.png"/ runat="server">
```

Code behind:

```
protected void Gridview_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        
        if (e.CommandName == CONSULTAR)
        {
            int id = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
            //campo id del objeto recogido del gridview, NO el index de la fila.
        }
    }
```

**No quiero recoger el index de la fila**, si no, el id (que está en la bbdd) del objeto que se muestra en el gridview, que es diferente para cada uno y no tiene que ver con el index de la fila.

Es decir, tengo un objeto en la fila 0 con el id 45. Yo quiero recoger con el CommandArgument ese id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Añadiendo en el ImageButton: `CommandArgument='<%# Bind("Id") %>'`

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="btnVer" CommandName="CONSULTAR" CommandArgument='<%# Bind("Id") %>' ImageUrl="~/ver.png"/ runat="server">
```

Y añadiendo `EnableViewState="false"` en el gridview son la solución.

Comment: No olvides [aceptar](/help/accepted-answer) tu respuesta cuando transcurra el tiempo mínimo.

Comment: Sí, gracias por avisarme.